# How do I fix the shading on these edges?

Tags: edges, shadows

I'm currently splitting off the hair of this model from the body before I fix up any issues with it, but the shading on the edges where the hair used to start is extremely dark and weird, despite being flat in wireframe. When I pop into sculpting mode it looks how you would expect it to look, so I'm not sure how to fix it. The extreme dark shadows are visible in material preview and rendered as well, in fact it looks even worse in rendered view because the shadows are darker and more extreme. The shading is visible when it's shaded flat or smooth.[image: Wireframe visible]

[image: Viewport Shading]

[image: Sculpting Mode]

[image: Rendered]

Answer (score 1):

I think your normals are messed up,
select all your faces in edit mode and press ALT+N, then click Set from faces.

Comment: That did it, right before I saw this I also figured out that turning off auto smooth in the normal panel achieved the same thing, but your method seems to be a lot better in the long run. Thank you!